# How to track an gmail's email through an api attach to an src tag of image?

Tags: grails

I want to track the email when somebody opens the image attach to that email. So i have been rendering an image byte through an api attach to the image tag rendered in email template. But whwn i am opening the email the src tag embeds the google proxy server address to my api address and not sending to my backend. background-image:url('https://ci6.googleusercontent.com/proxy/RMM_t4IFMpVLwbzLttQJroXN8EPE8atXTqU703UgLhhhytAO-_AvbFUjVyDXKGgcExvdyZtB7aBMSNHphT8n7rVxNMvsij1BsL4SCw=s0-d-e1-ft#https://resources.sparkwork.io/renderImage'). In this my actual api is https://resources.sparkwork.io/renderImage .So how can i solve this problem. Because when i am attaching some image url them its working and showing that image but when i am using my backend api then call is not coming to my backend to render that byte code of image. So any solution to solve this problem ?

Comment: Give each email's tracking pixel a unique URL, like a query string parameter.

Comment: background-image:url('https://ci6.googleusercontent.com/proxy/RMM_t4IFMpVLwbzLttQJroXN8EPE8atXTqU703UgLhhhytAO-_AvbFUjVyDXKGgcExvdyZtB7aBMSNHphT8n7rVxNMvsij1BsL4SCw=s0-d-e1-ft#https://resources.sparkwork.io/email-icons/emailbg.png')   this attachment works and i will attach in next comment the url which is not working

Comment: https://ci4.googleusercontent.com/proxy/fKKXkoUSnlB_yCCX4m7FbgxDgCGVd-_2moL1Hi6pYtcYG_VYCLzkFFWtTQKu85bkPsk9Oo3r3F-RKJHoBiF3DPv-s1s3LQbsNKh2DySVWCYh=s0-d-e1-ft#https://dev-api.sparkwork.io/api/emailTrackAPI/giftinstance   this is url which shown can u expalin how i can  do this tracking pixel unique in https://dev-api.sparkwork.io/api/emailTrackAPI/giftinstance